# Cytoscapejs mapData style

Tags: cytoscape.js

Trying to use the linear mapper style.  This particular property seems to be ignored; I can't get the visualization to respond.

```
node {
    any-property: mapData(priority, 1, 3, 0, 1);
}
```

I have verified in the Firefox interactive console that the nodes have the relevant `priority` property (with `cy.$("#some-node").data()`).  Everything else in my stylesheet is working as expected.  I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the particular mapper string `mapData(priority, 1, 3, 0, 1)` is parsed and works correctly.  You may have another style that later overrides this property later in your stylesheet.  Note also you can only use numerical values on properties that support them, like `width` or `height`.

If you think you've found a bug, please post enough information to fully reproduce your issue on the tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new

Comment: Could you assist in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995471/incrementing-the-size-of-nodes-in-cytoscape-js-by-a-specific-value . Thanks