# Incrementing the size of nodes in Cytoscape.js by a specific value

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using following json content for specifying the size of each node:

```
"data": {
 "id": "Name",
 "name": "NameID",
 "faveColor": "#86B342",
 "size": 120
}
```

Once the graph is generated, I wish to increment the size of all nodes by a particular value (which comes from user input).

Given the fact that

```
'data(size)' + value
```

isn't a legit operation, can anyone suggest an apt way to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us more of your code to go on to

Comment: you deleted the entire interaction history and your answer (just coz of some fear of downvote??) and expect me to waste more of my time with you now? Comments are supposed to help other users gain insights into what has already been tried and what can be tried further. Disappointed!

Comment: I was improving my answer. No need to be rude

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a int with string which won't seem to work. Instead try to get the property value and then add the input value to it.

You can edit the data value by passing a second argument to `nodes().data('element', 'value')`

Your code would look something like this:

```
cy.nodes().forEach(function(node){
  node.data('size', parseInt(node.data('size')) + 10); 
  console.log(node.data('size'))
});
```

Comment: point taken (infact I do acknowledge that adding an int to a string isn't legit)....assuming that you are trying to suggest selection of nodes of some particular id, i  am not aware how will I catch all nodes of the network (each node having a unique id)...more over, this approach, even for a single node,  tends to change the input data everytime a change is made (leaving little scope for reverting back to original state)...

Comment: and it doesn't work either for a single node.... (this.size + 100) is this a proper approach?

Comment: This is the best answer.  An alternative is to use functions in the stylesheet, so you can have `width: function(){ return n.data('size') + n.data('sizeDiff') }`, but that can have performance implications.  The `parseInt()` in the above answer is necessary only if `size` is a string.